# How do I move the Pycharm open files toolbar

Tags: pycharm

[image: Pycharm open files toolbar]

The open files ribbon/toolbar was inadvertently moved so that it is vertically displayed. I want to change it back to the standard horizontal layout. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the toolbar and change the "Tabs Placement" back to top.

[image: Right Click > Tabs Placement > Top]